# JSON List View Formatting using "Include File". Possible?

Tags: sharepoint-online, json, json-formatting

Is there a way to write my JSON in a single file and then use it in many lists views?

My situation is that I have a format that I want to use over and over again (more than a hundred) and the potential exists for this formatting to change, which would mean I would have to go into hundreds of views and make the same simple change over and over again vs. just one file.

In a "perfect world" I would write a json file (text) and just write the "include" statement where needed.  Is this possible?

I searched for this and have been unable to find anything, so guessing it doesn't exist, thought I'd ask here just in case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such a built-in functionality to reference a JSON file in list view formatting feature. You may consider using following workaround.

*[Set-PnPView](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnpview?view=sharepoint-ps)* Could apply the json format into the view.

```
 $listViewFormattingJSON = Get-Content -Raw -Path '{path}\Bulletin Board.json'

 Get-PnPList -Identity "{listname}" |Get-PnPView -Identity 'All Items'|Set-PnPView -Values @{CustomFormatter = $listViewFormattingJSON.ToString()}
```

I tested following JSON template and it works well

- [Bulletin Board](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-list-formatting/blob/master/view-samples/bulletin-board-format/README.md)
  [image]